# get "Cannot find coordinate operations" in GDAL 3; works in GDAL 2

Tags: gdal, proj, datum

I get the following error when trying to use GDAL 3.1.2 for computing the LLA from my custom gnomonic projections. Am I setting it up wrong? Missing some information/files? Would it be a misconfigured build? It worked fine for me in GDAL2.

```
Cannot find coordinate operations 
from `PROJCRS["Customized Gnomonic",BASEGEOGCRS["Customized WGS84",DATUM["Custom Datum",ELLIPSOID["WGS84 Radius + Elevation",6379509.75,inf,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]],CONVERSION["Gnomonic",METHOD["Gnomonic"],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",41.7480066139774,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-112.023800209591,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["False easting",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]' 
to `EPSG:4326'
```

Basic code to set it up:

```
var sr = new SpatialReference(null);
sr.SetProjCS("Customized Gnomonic");
sr.SetGeogCS("Customized WGS84", "Custom Datum", "WGS84 Radius + Elevation",
            _earthRadius + origin.Altitude, double.PositiveInfinity, null, 0.0, null, 1.0);
sr.SetGnomonic(origin.Latitude, origin.Longitude, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: There is a problem in the base geographic crs definition, wich has an infinite inverse flattening. Spheres have infinite inverse flattening but in the crs definition a zero for that parameter is interpreted as infinite. If you are trying to define a spheric datum, it must be `DATUM["Custom Datum",ELLIPSOID["WGS84 Radius + Elevation",6379509.75,0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]`. I don't know how to do it with the SetGeogCS() method.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to define something that is the same as WGS84 except for the radius of the earth.

Comment: Putting a zero in there in place of infinity does seem to get me farther. Thanks. That was an intentional GDAL2 -> GDAL3 change?

Comment: No, it is in the OGC standard definition for WKT representations of CRSes, section 8.2.1 (http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html#66) requirement a). Please, create the answer to your question, you can also accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, my issue was in using `double.PositiveInfinity` for the inverse flattening. The instructions specifically state to use zero when infinity is wanted. Apparently GDAL v2 supports either, but GDAL v3 only supports the zero input. See https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html#66